# Memoization in recursive expressions using a Map

Tags: haskell, memoization

I'm calculating some recursive expressions that are of the form,

[image: Where]

Now, let suppose that I have a list of indexes *t,u,v* `([t,u,v]::Int)` that for simplicity we can represent as `[[Int]]`, and I want to calculate the **R** function for each index `[t,u,v]` using something similar to the following code:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M

data HermiteStateIntegral = HermiteStateIntegral {
               getmapI :: M.Map [Int] Double
              ,getkeyI :: [[Int]]
               } deriving Show

calcIntegrals :: [Double] ->[[Int]] -> Double -> Vector Double
calcIntegrals vs listIndex f0 = U.unfoldr (calcRecExpr vs) seedI
seedI     = HermiteStateIntegral mapI0 listIndex
mapI0     = M.insert [0,0,0] f0 M.empty

calcRecExpr :: [Double] -> HermiteStateIntegral -> Maybe (Double,HermiteStateIntegral)
calcRecExpr vs hs@(HermiteStateIntegral m is)= do
           i <- safeHead is -- safeHead :: [a] -> Maybe a
           -- if the value associated with the indexes t,u,v is not in the map
           -- calculate it using the recursive equations
           let Just (val,newMap) = (lookupM i m) `mplus` (fun vs i m)
               newSt = hs{getmapI = newMap,getkeyI = tail is}
           return (val,newSt)


 where lookupM :: Ord k => k -> M.Map k a -> Maybe (a , M.Map k a)
       lookupM k m = do 
          val <- M.lookup k m
          return (val,m)  

fun :: [Double] -> [Int] ->  M.Map [Int] Double -> Maybe (Double, M.Map [Int] Double)
fun vs i m = -- fun computes the value associated with some index [t,u,v]
             -- that is not in the Map, using the recursive equations. And   
             -- insert this value on the Map.
```

So, I am using a `Map` to explicitly store the **R** subexpressions. If I want to calculate for example the index [1,1,1] the Map will store the indexes [0,1,1],[0,0,1],[0,0,0] that I can use in future calculations.

My questions are there: Is this an efficient implementation for explicitly caching the subexpression of **R** ? Is it there a more efficient way to express memoization using lazy evaluation?

Comment: There are many, many memoization packages on [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/).

Comment: Thanks!  I'm going to check them